# What's the generating function of the recurrence relationship $(n+1)a_{n+1} = 3a_n + 1$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

I was playing around with this interesting recurrence relationship $(n+1)a_{n+1} = 3a_n + 1$ with $a_0 = 1$, but I couldn't get the final answer $f' = 3f + \frac{1}{1-x}$.

I have attempted with two rules.

1. $ n \cdot f = x \frac{df}{dx}$
2. $ f_{n+1} = \frac{f-1}{x} $

I do recognize the part $\frac{1}{1-x}$ is just the geometric series but I couldn't see the connection.

The best that I got was $f' = 3f + \frac{x+1-f}{x}$ but still haven't got the desired answer.

Can anyone please explain this to me? Very appreciated!!

Comment: Let $f = \sum a_n x^n$, then $f' = \sum n a_n x^{n-1} = \sum (3 a_{n-1} + 1) x^{n-1} = 3 f + \frac{1}{1-x}$.

Comment: Please don't answer questions in the comments.

Comment: @Yimin I don't really get it if I start from the left side of the equation with two rules. I don't get the right side. Is $\sum(3a_{n-1} + 1)$ the same thing as $3a_n +1$, and $\sum x^{n-1}$ the same thing as $\sum x^n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take the recurrence relation $(n+1)a_{n+1}=3a_n+1$, multiply both sides by $x^n$, and sum over all $n\ge 0$.
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0} (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n=\sum_{n\ge 0}3a_nx^n+\sum_{n\ge 0} x^n
$$
It should be clear that $\sum_n 3a_nx^n=3f$, while $\sum_{n\ge 0}x^n=\frac1{1-x}$. For the sum on the left, we use the fact that $({n+1})x^n=\frac{d}{dx}[ x^{n+1} ]$ to write the sum as a derivative of $f$:
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n\ge 0} (n+1)a_{n+1}x^n
  &= \sum_{n\ge 0} a_{n+1} \frac{d}{dx}[x^{n+1}]
\\&= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\sum_{n\ge 0} a_{n+1} x^{n+1}\right]
\\&\stackrel1= \frac{d}{dx}\left[\sum_{n\ge 1} a_{n} x^{n}\right]
\\&\stackrel2= \frac{d}{dx}\left[-a_0+\sum_{n\ge 0} a_{n} x^{n}\right]
\\&= \frac{d}{dx}\left[-a_0+f\right]
\\&= f'.
\end{align}
$$
Explanations:

1. Here, we re-index the summation. The idea is that for any summation $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n$, we can define a new variable $m=n+1$, and use $m$ as the summation variable instead of $m$. As $n$ goes from $0$ to infinity, $m$ goes from $1$ to infinity, so $\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n =\sum_{m=1}^\infty b_{m-1}=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_{n-1}$. Apply this with $b_n=a_{n+1}x^{n+1}$.
2. Note that $\sum_{n\ge 1} a_{n} x^{n}$ is almost equal to the definition of $f$, except we are only summing over $n\ge 1$ instead of all $n\ge 0$. To fix this, we add and subtract the first term, $a_0$, hence the $-a_0$ out front.

Comment: Thank you so much :)